# Why emacs require XLIB_SKIP_ARGB_VISUALS=1

Tags: launcher

As many other Linux users EMACS is an important part of my installation. After installing EMACS on Elementary 5.0 Juno I couldn't manage to open it from the launcher icon, nor from the command line.

Searching the web I discovered that other people had the same problem on other Ubuntu derived distro, and the solution seems to open EMACS  from the cli with

```
XLIB_SKIP_ARGB_VISUALS=1  emacs
```

Although an alias into `~/.bashrc` solved the problem. This is quite strange and I still I don't get (my fault) what the issue is, after all EMACS has a central role for many Linux users.

Can somebody explain this solution, and whether there is a  better way to solve the issue without going through aliases?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get GNU Emacs work on elementary OS?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/797/how-to-get-gnu-emacs-work-on-elementary-os)