# How to get GNU Emacs from Flathub work on elementary OS?

Tags: appcenter, gtk, flatpak

To avoid Emacs installed through AppCenter crashing on opening, solution was actually explained [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/797/how-to-get-gnu-emacs-work-on-elementary-os).

But AppCenter only offers Emacs25 so I installed Emacs27 through Flathub (built in AppCenter)... except now the solution offered in the post mentioned above doesn't work anymore (different file paths etc.).

Any help? I think this could be as simple as copying `XLIB_SKIP_ARGB_VISUALS=1` somewhere else, but I wasn't able to understand where :(

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can run it with `env XLIB_SKIP_ARGB_VISUALS=1 flatpak run org.gnu.emacs`.

I used AppEditor to make a new menu entry.